# What is the antiderivative of $2^{(x-1)}$?

Tags: integration

Antiderivative of $2^{(x-1)}$

Which is the correct one?

$$= \frac{2^{(x-1)}}{\ln 2}$$

Or

$$=\frac{2^{(x-1)}}{2\ln 2}$$

Comment: Hey Bobonut welcome, have u tried differentiating both to see which solution is correct? If so could you edit your post and show me your work? :)

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 4):

**Hints:**

$$2^{\left(x-1\right)}=\frac{1}{2}2^x.$$

$$\int a^xdx=\frac{1}{\ln(a)}a^x+C \text{ for } a\ne 1 \text{ and } a>0.$$

You could also try to differentiate $2^{\left(x-1\right)}$:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(a^x\right)=a^x\ln(a).$$

[Set of basic rules](https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/derivatives-rules.html)

Answer (score 2):

$$
\int 2^{x-1}\, \mathrm{d}x =  \frac{1}{2} \int e^{\ln(2)x}\, \mathrm{d}x  \overset{\color{blue}{u=\ln(2)x}}{=} \frac{1}{2\ln(2)}\int e^{u}\mathrm{d}u = \frac{e^{\ln(2)x}}{2\ln(2)}+C = \boxed{\frac{2^{x-1}}{\ln(2)}+C}
$$

Answer (score 1):

We know that for a function $f(x)=a^x$

> $f'(x) = \ln(a) \cdot a^x $

So, we can therefore deduce that the integral of $f(x)=2^x$ is as follows:

> $$\int2^xdx = \frac{2^x}{\ln(2)}$$

And by the additive property of exponents, $2^{(x-1)} = 2^x\cdot2^{-1} = 2^x\cdot1/2 $

Therefore:

> $$\int2^{x-1}dx = \frac12 \cdot\int2^{x}dx =\frac12 \cdot\frac{2^x}{\ln(2)}$$

And again by the properties of exponents, we can simplify the $1/2$ value by subtracting one from the exponent of $2^x$:

> $$\int2^{x-1}dx = \frac{2^{(x-1)}}{\ln(2)}+c$$

So, your first answer was the correct one. Hope this helped!